# confirm in onDisconnect

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a popup extension where I want to execute an action after user confirmation when my popup exits. I tried the following code in my background script

```
browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (externalPort) {
    if (externalPort.name === 'myport') {
        externalPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
                 if (confirm("are you sure?"){
                       doIt();
                 }
        });
    }});
```

but then I get an error: `TypeError: window.gBrowser is undefined`. Evidently, I cannot have a dialog in my background script. Is there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: Look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript

Comment: I see. I guess it is not possible then? Since the popup window has already closed and I either have to create a new window or use the activeTab which would require extra permissions and not run on browser built-in pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addon's background page cannot show a confirmation dialog directly, it is a restriction of WebExtensions. There are some workarounds:

- Run a content script including `confirm()` in the active tab.
- Open a dialog window with `browser.windows.create({ url: 'dialog.html', type: 'popup' });` and communicate with the background page with WebExtensions APIs like `runtime.connect()` or `runtime.sendMessage()`.

Comment: Mmm.. The second option might be the best one for me. Is there a way to open the popup in the same way/style as my WebExtension popup is opened? (i.e., under the clicked button with certain size, no borders etc...). I can do the size/borders using CSS, but not sure how to show the popup under the button.

Comment: It is impossible to show a panel-like window from an addon without user's explicit action. You just can place the opened window at specified coordinates and size,  so just a workaround: 1) get `window.mozInnerScreenX`/`mozInnerScreenY`/`outerWidth`/`outerHeight` of the original popup (shown below the button), 2)send them to the background script, and 3) open a dialog based on the got coordinates. But it will have the title bar and the window frame.

Comment: I forgot to list one more possible workaround: a [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications). It is shown as a native notification on the platform, and looks cool than a regular dialog window. But Firefox doesn't support buttons in a notification, so I used it as: "click this if you want to cancel, otherwise the operation is done after 20sec."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. All of these options have their own problems. Coming back to the original problem. Is there a way to display a confirmation before the popup closes? I tried doing it in `onblur` but that didn't work (probably the window was already closed by then). Perhaps there's a way to prevent the automatic closing of the popup when it loses focus so that I can do it manually after showing the confirmation?

Comment: Sadly, it is impossible on WebExtensions. Basically WebExtensions API is designed as "user primary". Any blocking avaibalility are completely eliminated except some special cases (like webRequest's blocking filters). Indeed some API proposals I posted were rejected based on the design policy. If you find out any backdoor and successfully implemented a blocking UI, it can be reported by users as "abused" and banned from addons.mozilla.org. So I strongly recommend you to redesign your addon with non-blocking UI.

Comment: FYI: After these comments I've updated [my library to show dialog-like UI](https://github.com/piroor/webextensions-lib-rich-confirm#confirmation-in-a-popup). Now it allows you to open a modal-like window, so it possibly become a help for you. But I'm still afraid of a future it is reviewed as a spamming feature...